# Jar-With-Dependencies not including dependency

Tags: spring, maven, jar, dependencies, jar-with-dependencies

I am trying to package my applicaction using jar-with-dependencies

I am using spring-rabbit

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

which requires spring-retry. So I added (managed 1.0.3.RELEASE version) :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using the following plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.my.main.class.package.Mainclass</mainClass>
                        <packageName>com.my.main.class.package</packageName>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for ReplyCaller (included in RabbitTemplate).
When I inspect the contents of the jar there is no org/springframeowork/retry folder. How can I fix this?

---

Entire Pom File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.other</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>versionName</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>My Project<name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.other</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.amqp.version}</version>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>  
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>  
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksonVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksonVersion}</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.my.main.class.package.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <packageName>com.my.main.class.package</packageName>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>my-other-project-${commons.version}.jar</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.my.main.class.package.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <packageName>com.my.main.class.package</packageName>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>
        <properties>
            <jacksonVersion>1.9.12</jacksonVersion>
            <spring.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <spring.integration.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
            <spring.amqp.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</spring.amqp.version>
            <spring.boot.version>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show your full pom file otherwise it's hard to see the problem (if it is located in the pom file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resorted to removing jar-with-dependencies and using the springboot plugin.
I had to add dependencies I had in my other project to this project as well however.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.my.main.class.package.MainClass</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>
```